# MultiSelect in extjs Combobox

Tags: combobox, multi-select

I'm trying to multiselect in combobox of the Extjs, After I select the Items , the tpl index is rendered , want to render the value that's the displayfield selected when away out from the cell, how can I be able to Achieve this.

here's the code

```
function run() {

    var myStore=Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
        fields: ['busname', 'time', 'typebus',],
        pageSize:2,
        proxy: {
           type: 'memory',
          enablePaging: true
    },
        data: [{
            busname: 'ABCD',
            time: '15:30:00',
            typebus: 'AC Volvo',

        }, {
            busname: 'aaa',
            time: '13:30:00',
            typebus: 'Seater',

        },{
            busname: 'AAAA',
            time: '18:30:00',
            typebus: 'Sleeper',

        },{
            busname: 'ABCD',
            time: '19:30:00',
            typebus: 'AC Volvo',

        },]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        xtype :'gridpanel',
        itemId:'busTimegrid',
        pageSize:1,
        title: 'BUS DEATILS',
        mapperId:'getBusTime',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        columns: [{
            header: 'Bus Name',
            dataIndex: 'busname',
            editor: 'textfield'
        }, {
            text: 'Bus Time',
                dataIndex: 'time',
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            renderer: function (value) {
                if (value instanceof Date)
                    return Ext.util.Format.date(value, 'H:i:s');
                else
                return value;
            },
            flex: 1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'timefield',
                format: 'H:i:s',
                allowBlank: true,
                maskRe: /[0-9,:]/,
                listeners: {
                beforeselect: function(timefield, record) {
                var grid = timefield.up('grid');
                if(grid.store.find('time', record.data.disp) != -1) {
                Ext.Msg.alert("Bus time already exist.");
                return false;
    }
  }
}
            }
        }, {
            header: 'Bus TYpe',
            dataIndex: 'typebus',
            editable:true,
            renderer: function (value) {
                if (Ext.isNumber(value)) {
                    var store = this.getEditor().getStore();
                    return store.findRecord('id', value).get('name');
                }
                return value;
            },
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combo',
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'id',
                editable:true,
                forceSelection:true,
                multiSelect: true,
                    displayTpl: '<tpl for=".">' +
                    '{name}' +
                    '<tpl if="xindex < xcount">, </tpl>' +
                    '</tpl>',
                store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    fields: ['id', 'name'],
                    data: [{
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'AC Volvo'
                    }, {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'Seater'
                    }, {
                        id: 3,
                        name: 'Sleeper'
                    }]
                })

            }
        }],
        selModel: 'cellmodel',
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'cellediting',
            clicksToEdit: 1,
        },
        listners: [{
            fn: 'onUsernamefieldBlur',
            event: 'blur',
            delegate: 'busname'
        }],
        onUsernamefieldBlur: function (textfield, e, eOpts) {

        if (textfield.getValue() === '') {
            Ext.Msg.alert("Busname can't be empty");
            textfield.setFocus(true);
        }
    },
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
            dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            store: myStore,   // same store GridPanel is using
            dock: 'bottom',
            displayInfo: true
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()

    });
    var gridRow = myStore.getModifiedRecords();
 Ext.each(gridRows, function (gridRow) {
     var dirtyInd = myStore.indexOf(gridRow);
     var newTime = new Date(store.getAt(dirtyInd).data.time);
   },
   myStore.each(function (record, idx) {
   var newT = new Date(record.get('time'));
   if (Ext.Date.diff(newTime, newT,Ext.Date.SECOND)=== 0)
   {
   samebustime = true;
   }
   })); 
   if(samebustime){
       Ext.Msg.alert('Warning','Same time occured')
   }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arshad3641/pen29y6j/1/)

Comment: Do you really need id for typebus? If not then `valueField: 'name'` will work for you.

Comment: yes, because i need that data to be store in database, when remote storage being used..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some modification to your original source code. You might like it or not. But in this code you get what you have asked for. I am not sure if that is exactly what you want.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        run();
        window.show();
    }
});


function run() {

    var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
        fields: ['busname', 'time', 'typebus',],
        pageSize: 2,
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            enablePaging: true
        },
        data: [{
            busname: 'ABCD',
            time: '15:30:00',
            typebus: 'AC Volvo',

        }, {
            busname: 'aaa',
            time: '13:30:00',
            typebus: 'Seater',

        }, {
            busname: 'AAAA',
            time: '18:30:00',
            typebus: 'Sleeper',

        }, {
            busname: 'ABCD',
            time: '19:30:00',
            typebus: 'AC Volvo',

        },]
    });

    var typebusStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'typeBusStore',
        fields: ['id', 'name'],
        data: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'AC Volvo'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Seater'
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Sleeper'
        }]
    })

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        itemId: 'busTimegrid',
        pageSize: 1,
        title: 'BUS DEATILS',
        mapperId: 'getBusTime',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        columns: [{
            header: 'Bus Name',
            dataIndex: 'busname',
            editor: 'textfield'
        }, {
            text: 'Bus Time',
            dataIndex: 'time',
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            renderer: function (value) {
                if (value instanceof Date)
                    return Ext.util.Format.date(value, 'H:i:s');
                else
                    return value;
            },
            flex: 1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'timefield',
                format: 'H:i:s',
                allowBlank: true,
                maskRe: /[0-9,:]/,
                listeners: {
                    beforeselect: function (timefield, record) {
                        var grid = timefield.up('grid');
                        if (grid.store.find('time', record.data.disp) != -1) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert("Bus time already exist.");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            header: 'Bus TYpe',
            dataIndex: 'typebus',
            editable: true,
            renderer: function (value, md, record) {
                var retValue = Array();
                if (Ext.isArray(value)) {
                    Ext.each(value, function(id) {
                        retValue.push(Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('typeBusStore').findRecord('id', id).get('name'));
                    });
                }

                if (retValue.length > 0) {
                    return retValue.join(", ");
                }
                return value;
            },
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combo',
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'id',
                editable: true,
                forceSelection: true,
                multiSelect: true,
                displayTpl: '<tpl for=".">' +
                '{name}' +
                '<tpl if="xindex < xcount">, </tpl>' +
                '</tpl>',
                store: typebusStore

            }
        }],
        selModel: 'cellmodel',
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'cellediting',
            clicksToEdit: 1,
        },
        listners: [{
            fn: 'onUsernamefieldBlur',
            event: 'blur',
            delegate: 'busname'
        }],
        onUsernamefieldBlur: function (textfield, e, eOpts) {

            if (textfield.getValue() === '') {
                Ext.Msg.alert("Busname can't be empty");
                textfield.setFocus(true);
            }
        },
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            store: myStore,   // same store GridPanel is using
            dock: 'bottom',
            displayInfo: true
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()

    });
    var gridRows = myStore.getModifiedRecords();
    console.log(gridRows)
    var samebustime = false;
    Ext.each(gridRows, function (gridRow) {
        var dirtyInd = myStore.indexOf(gridRow);
        var newTime = new Date(store.getAt(dirtyInd).data.time);

        myStore.each(function (record, idx) {
            var newT = new Date(record.get('time'));
            if (Ext.Date.diff(newTime, newT, Ext.Date.SECOND) === 0) {
                samebustime = true;
            }
        })
    });
    if (samebustime) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Warning', 'Same time occured')
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzmamepu/)

Comment: This worked for the static store perfectly, Charming,.. 
Now Im trying to   load the combobox remotely, So i'm trying to load the store using  `var store = this.getEditor().getStore`  but it says like `this.getEditor` is not a function , But ti have used the same in a differnet function , there it works perfectly, Can you please say where I'm going wrong

Comment: Your `this` seems to be `gridpanel`. You need to be in the particular grid to get its editor. Roughly doing `this.columns[2].getEditor().getStore()` will get you store of the bus type editor.

Comment: how to specify a remote store inside the editor , in the sense, for eg: i'm not defining the typeBustore, and I get data using a query with the help of mapperId, so with that mapper id a store will be created ..... How to mention a remote store inside the editor as in like `store: 'something'`

Comment: _Your this seems to be gridpanel. You need to be in the particular grid to_ _get its editor. Roughly doing this.columns[2].getEditor().getStore() will _get you store of the bus type editor ....... when i used thios and printed the **retValue** in console gave me a false values.. not the right ones, it gave me other column values

Comment: If you try in this example provided in fiddle, you will get correct store, I have tested it in the fiddle and provided you with the answer. Have you checked this like with your code that you are doing or with the code in fiddle I provided in my answer?

Comment: Yeah that's working fine for the bustype cell column, But when I touch the other cell take as _bustime_ , I get this Below

`[W] XTemplate evaluation exception: this.getEditor is not a function`

`ext-all-debug.js:47836 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null`

Comment: i'm trying to get the store as `var store = this.columns[4].getEditor().getStore();`

and when printing in console i get as `[object Object ]` and not the store name... can you please help me with this buddy

Comment: you can use "debugger" in your code instead of console.log and do some debugging in developer tool. you cannot get store, if you haven't used one. which is the case for bust time field. :) try debugging. its fun :)

Comment: Okie Buddy Thanks much